# Java protocol buffers - reflection

Tags: java, reflection, protocol-buffers

I'm new to protocol buffers and exploring reflection methods. I see a method GetReflection() to get the reflection interface in C++, however, I couldn't find a similar method in Java. Does anyone know how to get the reflection interface in Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Java equivalent to the Protobuf-C++ "reflection" interface is simply the `com.google.protobuf.Message` interface.  All message objects implement this, and it has methods like `getField()` that read arbitrary fields by descriptor.  Similarly, all builders implement `Message.Builder` which has `setField()` and such.  Unlike in C++, this functionality is not delegated to a separate object.

Answer (score 1):

Can you describe why you are trying to do ???, I I know that I will tailor the answer with that in mind

- As others have indicated you can use reflection on any class in java.
- The java version provides [DynamicMessage Class](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/DynamicMessage.java). Depending on what you are tryind to do, you may find [DynamicMessage Class](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/DynamicMessage.java) is what you are after. This class allows you read an arbitary Protocol-Buffer using a proto descriptor and access the fields via getField methods etc. You will need the protocol buffer in Proto-Descriptor (you can use the --descriptor_set_out= parameter of the protoc command to get it).
- If you do not optermise for speed, the protoc command will generate classes that use reflection.

Comment: Thanks, Bruce. I checked out some C++ code for protocol buffers and I was able to find some methods like GetReflection(). However, I couldn't find something similar in Java. May be there is another way  or other set of methods for doing this reflection stuff in Java? To be more specific, I was trying to get the very similar methods in Java :) Does that clarify what I'm trying to figure out? :)

Comment: Also, I know the standard java provides reflection mechanism, however, I'm trying to use the one from protocol buffers. For example, we have protobuf.Message.Reflection in C++. But I couldn't find this in Java.

Answer (score -5):

The reflection interface can be found in the [reflection package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html).  Generally one would access the interface by using a [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) instance.

```
public static void main(String[] $)
{
    Class clazz = String.class;
    System.out.println(clazz.getName()); // "java.lang.String"
}
```

Comment: The question is not about Java-reflection. It's about protocol buffer reflection.

Comment: this answer is out of the question.